# Distributed memcached in cloud deployment with Docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, memcached

I am using docker-compose in my dev environment. I have a simple web application, which is using a sql database and a memcached container.

Now, if one day I would like to go to production, what should I do in order to have my memcached instance truly distributed?

If I simply scale up all the services specified in my Docker-compose, I will end up having independent memcached nodes, not really a cluster. Should I re-write my Docker-compose for prod env, so that I have each of my services in its own Docker-compose yml file? What are the benefits of using Docker-compose then? I just could deploy each service as individual Docker container scaled up to desired amount.

What are the best practices of using Docker-compose in cloud deployment and how to achieve distributed cluster setup?

Comment: It would probably be better to ask this question on https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A memcached "cluster" isn't really a cluster. Each memcached instance is independent and isolated. It's up to the client handle the sharding and route to the instance it wants for reads and writes.

If you want a cache system that does cluster and replicate, consider using [Redis](https://get-reddie.com/blog/redis4-cluster-docker-compose/).

If you want to turn your Docker compose configurations into a cluster, use [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/).